# iOS: Wrapping asynchronous call in a method

Tags: ios, objective-c, asynchronous

I have been wondering if this following scenario is possible:

Given a function `foo` defined as

```
- (void)foo:(int)n action:(SEL)selector
{
    // do something, maybe fetching data from server
    ...
    // at a later point
    [self performSelector:@selector(selector) withObject:returnObject];
}
```

**NOTE**: `foo` is a blackbox function that was given to you. It cannot be altered in anyway

---

One would normally create function `bar`

```
- (id)bar:(id)x
{
    return x;
}
```

and call `[self foo:n action:@selector(bar:)]` to get result in the function `bar`;

---

Instead, I wonder if it is possible to wrap the function and make it synchronized such that I only need to call

```
- (id)foobar:(int)n;
```

to get the return value that would normally get returned by above `bar`

Comment: Why not just do `- (id)foobar:(int)n { return [self foo:nil]; }`?

Comment: `[self foo:nil]` would not return anything as you can see the `void` return type. Not sure what this does.

Comment: Sorry, meant `[self bar:nil];`.

Comment: @mipadi That would skip the "do something, maybe fetching data" bit.

Comment: @mipadi Right... that would pretty much do nothing like Aaron suggests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to call `foo:action:` with a no-op selector that saves whatever object is passed into it in an instance variable, and then call `bar:` manually:

```
- (void)saveAsIvar:(id)var
{
    _returnObject = var;
    [_fooLock unlock];
}

- (id)bar:(id)x { return whatever; }

- (id)foobar:(int)n
{
    [_fooLock lock];
    [self foo:n action:@selector(saveAsIvar:)]
    while (YES) {
        if ([_fooLock tryLock]) {
            return [self bar:_returnObject];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How would `foobar` knows when the _returnObject has been saved? Because `foo` is asynchronous, and can take a long time to reach `saveAsIvar`

Comment: @Byte: You could use locks. Updated answer to show example.

Comment: This should work. You don't need `bar` anymore. And maybe a `sleep(x)` in the `while` loop would be ok too. +1 for now, let see if there are other ideas :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What you are struggling with is that foo is flawed. It should not be dropping the result of bar. The selector that foo calls (bar) should do the completion code.

If you want to make this work with foo as written, you're going to have to do some fairly gross hacking and slashing.

I would:

Make foo post a notification once it's complete, and put the result in the user dictionary of the notification.

Make foobar take a completion block. Have it register a notification listener that takes the result value out of the user info dictionary of the notification and passes it to the completion block.

Comment: This is definitely a hack and slash :) And I completely agree that that the implementation of foo could have been better. Sadly some codes are not yours to change. We only have to adapt. But your method should work so +1

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you are trying to create dynamic function names. So for example I had a method -(void)fizz:(id)x then I would call -(id)foofizz:(int)n

Although I haven't tried it and it doesn't sound like a good idea but it could be possible by using message forwarding
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCRuntimeGuide/Articles/ocrtForwarding.html

Comment: Sorry about the confusion. I redid the question, hopefully it makes more sense.

Comment: I don't think the OP is asking about dynamic function names; they're asking how to implement `- (id)foobar:`.

Answer (score 0):

The usual way to accomplish this in objective c is by using blocks, which are basically chunks of code that are passed around like function pointers. You will add a block as a parameter to your foo method. When foo completes its work, it should then invoke the block that was passed to it, allowing any client to perform work on completion of foo.

In your .h:

```
- (void)foo:(int)n withCompletion:(void (^)(id fooResult))completion;
```

In your .m

```
- (void)foo:(int)n withCompletion:(void (^)(id fooResult))completion {

   //do foo stuff

   //invoke the completion block with the result of foo

   if (completion) {
       completion(someResult);
   }
}
```

Now in your client class (that is, whoever is trying to use foo). Call foo like so:

```
[someObject foo:someInt withCompletion:^(id fooResult) {

    [self bar:fooResult];
}];
```

Here the client calls foo and specifies what to do on completion, in this case, call bar with the result of foo.

Here are the [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/00_Introduction.html) where you can learn more about Objective-C blocks.

Comment: Thank you for your input. If `foo` weren't an untouchable black box, I would have accepted your answer. Maybe that note was too low, I have updated the note to be next to the foo implementation. Sorry for the confusion.